# How can I retrieve a composite class in EF Code First, having specified a relation on multi tier app?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an interesting problem :
I created a class called, let's say, "Container" wich has a member of type "Contained"
It would look like:

`public class Container
    {
       public Contained cnt{ get; set; }
    }`

The model contains both tables, and my DB looks like:
Containers(PK:id FK:Contained_ContainedId)
Contained(PK:ContainedId)

EF Code first correcty maps this atribute as a foreign key in the Contined table.
The problem comes when I want to retrieve these objects using LINQ:

`Container Con=(from Object in PersistentManager.Containers.OfType<Container> select Object).SingleOrDefault();`

This way (or either casting an anonymous type), I get a Container. The problem is, the reference to the Contained object is allways null. I think this is made on purpose for the sake of performance, but, this time, I need it to recover the full object.
Intellitrace shows it's not even joining tables, so i guess something else should be specified
Any ideas?

Allrigth, thanks to Basic, I have solved the issue using the include clause.
I think there SHOULD be a way to use lazy loading on context closed environment (multi tier patterns allways recomend disposing these objects)

Comment: Are you using Lazy Loading? If not, you'll need to `include` the relevant tables for the various contained entities

Comment: I think I'm not using it.. They are included and mapped to the database. I think it should be something specified on the query.. Am I wrong?

Comment: I _believe_ what you need is something like ... `(from PersistentManager.Containers.Include("Contained").OfType...`

Comment: Excellent, this sure works!!
One more thing, how can I include 2 objects?
Is there a way to allow lazy loading on multi tier apps?
The problem is, my DbContext is often closed when I need this info

Comment: I'll post as an answer with some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...

You need to `Include` relevant tables. eg

```
(from PersistentManager.Containers.Include("Contained").OfType...
```

You can include multiple tables each time

```
(from PersistentManager.Containers.Include("Contained").
Include("OtherContained").
Include("Contained.SomeOtherLinkedType").
OfType...
```

etc etc

Lazy loading on n-Tier depends on how you want to handle the data. I personally prefer to enable Lazy loading in the DAL/BL but pass non-EF DTOs (effectively identical to your entities but not mapped) up to the UI. This way, the BL can get the data it wants easily and the UI gets "inert" objects.